# I'm trying to import a daily filename_YYYYMMDD from a directory, but cannot get the VBA codes to import the file as a text file into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim fs, f As Object

    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "Filename_" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, 0)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;strPath", Destination:= _
    Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

'-----I'm not sure what I'm missing above in VBA, but obviously, it works when I point to the filename manually in the macro set-up-----------------------------

```
Sub Macro1()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Desktop\filename_20140101.txt", Destination:= _
    Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

' THANKS!!!!

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please mark as answered, if not what further issue are you experiencing?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, was away for a few days!  It works great. Thank you!!!

Comment: Great to hear your import is working. When you have asked a question and the issue has been solved it is best if you could mark the answer you found most useful as 'the answer' (to the left of the answer is a 'Tick' outline that when clicked turns green), this not only gives recognition to the person who put effort into helping you but also tells others that there is an answer so they don't spend time looking into your issue and trying to solve something that has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I will do that when I'm on PC tomorrow. Don't see it on my iPhone now. Sorry for lack of etiquette  in the Q&A "room" ;)  Still new to this forum!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you aren't actually passing `strPath` to the connection and also you are missing the file extension (.txt), you need it as:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & strPath, Destination:= _
    Range("A1"))
```

With your `strPath` set to the full path including extension:

```
strPath = "C:\Desktop\Filename_" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt"
```